# Group By en Laravel con SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo la siguiente query en Laravel a través de query builder:

```
$objective_risk = DB::table('objective_risk')
              ->join('objectives','objectives.id','=','objective_risk.objective_id')
              ->join('risks','risks.id','=','objective_risk.risk_id')
              ->where('objectives.organization_id','=',(int)$org)
              ->groupBy('risks.id')
              ->orderBy('risks.name')
              ->select('risks.name','objective_risk.id as riskid')
              ->get();
```

Esta query funciona perfectamente conectándome a MySQL, pero ahora necesito que me funcione también en SQL Server, lo cual me arroja el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
La columna 'risks.name' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en 
una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY. (SQL: select [risks].[name], [risks].[id] 
from [objective_risk] inner join [objectives] on [objectives].[id] = [objective_risk].
[objective_id] inner join [risks] on [risks].[id] = [objective_risk].[risk_id] where 
[objectives].[organization_id] = 28 group by [risks].[id] order by [risks].[name] asc)
```

En el fondo tengo una tabla de riesgos y otra de objetivos (con relación muchos a muchos), y quiero obtener el id de la relación (objective_risk.id) y el nombre del riesgo, e intento hacer la agrupación por el id del riesgo (considerando que es una relación muchos a muchos para que no se repitan), lo que en MySQL funciona perfecto pero no así en SQL Server.

Espero puedan orientarme un poco.

Comment: ¿ya probaste agregando la columna en mención a GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1):

Mirá, estas seleccionando dos campos risks.name y objective_risk.id pero está agrupando por uno solo, eso en SQL server no es válido, a menos que uses una función de agregación sobre risks.name, pero entiendo que no es el caso. Como te sugirió @Shaz, hay que agregar risks.name al Group by.